# SIM7080 UART Noise interfacing with PIC18F4550

Tags: pic, modbus, modem, simcom

I'm working on a project where I read data over Modbus line and send it in the cloud service through a SIM7080 CATM modem. I'm using PIC18F4550 as MCU.

As that PIC18F has just one UART module, I'm using a CD4066 to select which peripherals I want to communicate - Modbus line (RS485) or send AT commands to the CATM modem.

The SIM7080 dev board works with 3V3 UART and my PIC18F works with 5V, so a level converter is needed.

I'm having some trouble receiving the modem AT response - analyzing in my oscilloscope and in logic analyzer, it shows a very noisy pattern in the TX line of SIMCOM7080.

Before designing the PCB, I'm using a PIC18F4550 development board + protoboard.

I'm using a L7805 to power up the PIC module and AMS1117-3V3 to power up SIM7080.

Maybe that behavior in SIM7080 UART is related with AMS1117 maximum output current (1A)? I've tried to check the output SIMCOM TX signal directly, not connecting in the level converter, but the noise pattern keeps (as the oscilloscope picture).

Thank you,

[image: Logic analyzer view]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems that SIMCOM module is not healthy, normally you should measure a steady 1.8V on the TXD pin when no communication is happening. Check that you have all the required connections made, monitor VDD (3V3) output and see if it's stable.

Comment: @AndrejsGasilovs You're right, thanks. The TXD pin from breakout board was showing 1.4V instead the 3V3 (already leveled from 1.8V to 3V3).
When I took off from my 3V3 - 5V TTL converter from SIMCOM TXD to PIC RX, the 3V3 showed up greatly and I received the AT commands response in the logic analyzer.
Now I will find another way to convert that 3V3 to 5V UART without interfering the TXD signal..

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do this with dev boards. If you design a PCB with a cellular modem you need 33pF and 10pF on pretty much every trace. They filter out transmissions on 'about' 900MHz and 'about' 1800MHz. You may need others if you're using other LTE bands.

You schematic is missing these out on the base of all of the transistors. If you use a wideband transistor, it will amplify the RF and cause these problems. You really need to specify a transistor with a low frequency response for the level shifting.

We've had PCBs switch themselves off because the PWRKEY open collector transistor was too responsive to RF!

You also need a fast (as in able to respond quickly to current demands) and stable power source. A Li-ion battery is not good enough on its own, you would also need some low-ESR bypass capacitors next to the baseband and RF power inputs to the modem.

You really see issues with transmission interference on the UART traces. Some modems will also shut down if the power isn't good enough.

There is another gotcha with these modems - reflections from the antenna. If it's not correctly matched power being reflected back into the modem from the aerial will shut it down. I've been caught out by this.

SIMCOM modems are good enough to handle quite a mis-matched antenna though.